# Inability to Make External API calls

Tags: python, django, api, django-views

I am getting this error in my terminal while making some External API request call

I am following the documentation from here https://paystack.com/docs/api/#dedicated-nuban

```
def create_nuban(request):
    url = "https://api.paystack.co/dedicated_account"
    payload = {
        "customer":481193,
        "preferred_bank":"providus-bank"
    }

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer SECRET_KEY',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data= payload)
    print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Error message on the terminal

```
b'{\n  "status": false,\n  "message": "Request body could not be parsed. Make sure request 
body matches specified content-type: \'application/json\'",\n  "data": 
{\n    "parser_message": "Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0",\n    
"body": "customer=481193&preferred_bank=providus-bank"\n  }\n}'
```

Comment: try `json=payload` instead of `data=payload`

Comment: Thanks for responding, I am really grateful

Comment: I have just tried json=payload but i am now getting this error saying "b'{\n  "status": false,\n  "message": "Access Denied"\n}'"

Comment: I have also made sure to input my secret key while making the request, so I am not sure why i could be getting that response "access denied"

Comment: I am using my secret test key, maybe the api only accept live key for creating a sub-account. Do you have any idea about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

Use json instead of data which internally json dums your payload.

```
def create_nuban(request):
    url = "https://api.paystack.co/dedicated_account"
    payload = {
        "customer":481193,
        "preferred_bank":"providus-bank"
    }

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer SECRET_KEY',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: I have just tried json=payload but i am now getting this error saying "b'{\n "status": false,\n "message": "Access Denied"\n}'"

Comment: It's because your API requires authentication. If so, you need to provide an Authorization token or other required cookies in your request header.

Comment: You must replace the value for `Authorization` with a valid token.

Comment: I have added the neccessary authentication which is the secret_key

Comment: you can kindly check the documentation here, i was asked to provide only the secret key which i did but i still kept getting an invalid response, https://paystack.com/docs/api/#dedicated-nuban

Comment: I am using my secret test key, maybe the api only accept live key for creating a sub-account. Do you have any idea about that

Comment: Can you check the response status_code? If it is 401, or 403, the problem would be with your credentials. As far as it's related to code, this snippet is fine. It's a matter of credentials. I would double-check the `customer` and `Authorization` values.

Comment: Well, it's clearly related two those values I mentioned. The code is just fine. Good luck

Comment: I would like you to kindly help with this question. Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525767/dynamic-request-of-data-from-api-endpoint-in-djangorestframework