# Dynamic request of data from API endpoint in DjangoRestFramework

Tags: json, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am making some API calls from an external source but would like to make it dynamic instead of manually putting the reference number in my views in the DRF UI provided.

What I want is that in my DRF UI, I should have a field whereby when I enter a reference number, I should get the response from from the API, I am successfully doing this manually but I want to make it dynamic from the DRF UI.

I would also like to get a better formatted JSON Response in my DRF UI. An image is below to better explain what I meant

Views.py

```
class Paystack(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        url = "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/{{REFERENCE_NO}}"
        payload = {}
        files = {}
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer SECRET_KEY',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data= payload, files=files)
        return Response(response)

    def post(self, request):
        url = "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/{{REFERENCE_NO}}"
        payload = {}
        files = {}
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer SECRET_KEY',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data= payload, files=files)
        return Response(response)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import *
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('paystack', Paystack, basename='paystack')

urlpatterns = [
    path('paystack/', Paystack.as_view(), name='paystack'),
]
```

Presently, my DRF UI looks likes this, [image: MY DRF UI]

Comment: Regarding the response, given that questions must be focused, please open another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to get reference_id in your DRF UI, you must either define a serializer and catch the value from that, or, you can define a URL pattern which asks for a reference ID.

You can do this

**In urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('paystack/<str:reference_id>', Paystack.as_view(), name='paystack'),
```

]

**In your views.py**

```
class Paystack(APIView):

    def get(self, request, reference_id):
        url = f"https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/{reference_id}"
        payload = {}
        files = {}
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer SECRET_KEY',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data= payload, files=files)
        return Response(response)
```

Comment: Wow, am so glad, it worked almost as i wanted but if i would like to enter it in my field like a post object so that it returns the data, how do i go about that

Comment: In order words, I will like to use the serializer method

Comment: But what I am confused about is that, when I used serializer.py then I have to specify my models.py also, as it needs to serialize the data in my data coming from the database. but now, i am not using an models which is what is confusing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the correct way to go. You must use the post method only when you are modifying the database. By default, DRF does not render `kwargs` as a field. But, if you use other API documentation tools like Swagger, they would give the filed you want.